# Alternativa Cron Job

Tags: linux, cron

Preciso rodar esse cron job

```
***** wget --spider -O - http://dominio.com/cron >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Porém a hospedagem não deixa eu usar ***">"*** , teria alguma alternativa para essa tarefa?

olha o que aparece. http://prnt.sc/e9fni8

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Assim , http://prnt.sc/e9fni8

Answer (score 0):

Simplismente remova o redirecionamento, ficando assim:

```
wget --spider -O - http://dominio.com/cron
```

Comment: Não funcionou, agora meu site entrou em um loop infinito e recebo esse erro "Service Temporarily Unavailable"

Comment: Você quer monitorar o status do seu site? Existem serviços para isso, que rodam fora do server.

Comment: Na verdade é um sistema de postagem automática para o instagram, que você consegue agendar as publicações.

Comment: E você utiliza cron do SO para isso? Não fica ruim de mudar o agendamento? Sugiro utilizar recurso de schedule e implementar no seu sistema o serviço de agendamento.

Comment: O cron já tá pronto, e funcionava exatamente como eu queria em outro servidor. Depois que mudei de servidor ele não deixa eu rodar o esse cron por causa do ">".